# Trouble posting to database, from iOS app

Tags: ios, sql, json

I'm having a problem updating my database from an iOS app...

Sql statements

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("server_name","user_name","user_code","table_name");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'table.name'
$sql = "SELECT * table_name";

// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
// If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
// to hold the data
$resultArray = array();
$tempArray = array();

// Loop through each row in the result set
while($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
// Add each row into our results array
$tempArray = $row;
array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
}

// Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
echo json_encode($resultArray); 
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES('1')";


// Close connections
mysqli_close($result);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

My iOS code

```
for (Tickets *items in _feedItems){
if ([resultText.text isEqual:(id) items.ticketNumber]) {

    status.text = @"Match found";

//Contacting database------------------------------

    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TicketDate=%@", items.ticketDate];

    NSData *postData = [strURL dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding 
allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webservice.com"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-   
Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(conn)
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
    }

//Contacting database END-------------------------------------------


    break;


}else {

    status.text = @"Match not found";
}
}
```

I get a Connection Succesful from the NSLog but there is nothing getting updated in my database.

I'm trying to manually type in a ticket number with an app, and if that matches with a ticket in the database (it works), then I want the the ticketDate to change from 0 to 1.

But it does not change :/

Comment: Can you log on the serveur side the response you got from the iOS app?

Comment: where u check ed in simulator  or device

Comment: I get:2014-06-26 17:31:31.690 AppNetScanner[1991:60b] Connection Successful
2014-06-26 17:31:31.833 AppNetScanner[1991:60b] response=

Comment: So I can check how many tickets where to the show, of the tickets sold.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling

```
[conn start];
```

to have your request effectively sent. I.e.:

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[conn start];
```

You should also be aware that the request will be sent **asynchronously**, this means that you will not get the response right after calling start. What you should do, if you want to stay with an async connection, is implement a [data delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate), and at least its `– connection:didReceiveData:`, `– connectionDidFinishLoading:`, and `connection:didFailLoadingWithError:` methods.

Alternatively, you might consider sending the request synchronously, i.e., just replacing

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

with:

```
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

But this kind os request will block your app UI, unless you send them on a background thread.

Comment: Would it block? I mean...just want to change a 0 to a 1, in the database.

Comment: the network request will take some time, even if it's a fraction of a second you will notice it. on the other hand, go the sync way just for a test and to troubleshoot your server, then you can implement the delegate (if you ever need to get a response or worry about detecting failed requests, otherwise you would not be strictly needed).

Comment: Ok....it's just that there so few working tutorials on how to update/post a mysql database from an iOS app. Probably alotta noob details that i'm missing. Every tutorial I find is about fetching and parsing....and that I got working.

Answer (score 0):

In the database I have a row with a ticketNumber and ticketDate. If the number typed into my app is the same as a ticketNumber in my database, then i want the same row's ticketDate to change from 0 to 1.

Comment: Thats the overall idea with this.